# Update delay on Google Drive api

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I'm building a synchronisation service that keeps track of all the changes in a specific Google Drive folder.

Following this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) I built this function:

```
public function whatChangesAreThere()
{
    $response = [];
    $pageToken = $this->lastPageToken;
    while ($pageToken != null) {
        $listChanges = $this->googleDriveService->changes->listChanges($pageToken, [
            'spaces' => 'drive'
        ]);

        collect($listChanges->changes)->each(function ($change) use (&$response) {
            $fileResponse = [];
            $fileResponse["type"] = $change->type;
            if (array_has($change, "file.name")) {
                $fileResponse["fileName"] = $change->file->name;
            }
            $fileResponse["kind"] = $change->kind;
            $fileResponse["removed"] = $change->removed;
            $fileResponse["teamDriveId"] = $change->teamDriveId;
            $fileResponse["time"] = $change->time;

            $response[$change->fileId] = $fileResponse;
        });
        $pageToken = $listChanges->nextPageToken;
    }

    $this->storeNewPageToken($listChanges->newStartPageToken);

    return $response;
}
```

The function seems to work: when I change something in the file I get the name of the file that changed in my application. The problem is that there can be up to 1-2 minutes delay between changing the file and getting the file listed in this function.

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if this dealy is due to something else.

What do you think?